# Expansion in Schur function of negative binomial exponent

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, symmetric-functions, algebraic-combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I want to know if there exist a known expansion or can be derived of the polynomial
$$ \prod_{i=1}^{m}\prod_{j= 1}^{n}(1-z(x_i + y_i))^{-w} \tag{*}$$
in terms of Schur function. That is asking for (*) can be written in the from
$$ \sum_{\lambda , \nu} d_{\lambda , \nu} s_{\lambda}({\bf{x}})s_{\mu}({\bf{y}}) $$
what is this $d_{\lambda , \nu}$ ? $\lambda$, $\mu$ are ranging over all partitions.

Let me give you things that are close to the expression known in literature and can be found in *I.G Macdonald Symmetric function and Hall polynomials*.

$$\prod_{i=1}^{m}(1-x_i)^{-n} = \sum_{\lambda, \ell({\lambda})\leq m} d_{\lambda}(n)s_{\lambda} \,\,\, (n\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1})\tag{**}$$
where $$d_{\lambda}(n) = \prod_{(i,j)\in \lambda}\frac{n+j-i}{h_{\lambda}(i,j)} $$, $\ell(\lambda)$ denote the length of $\lambda$, $h_{\lambda}(i,j)$ is the hook length.

If $m=1$ we can see that that imply that the length of the partition lambda can be only 1, hence $\lambda$ can be of the from $(k)$, where $k$ is a positive integer.
hence
$$(1-x_1)^{-n} = \sum_{k\geq 1}\prod_{i=1}^{k}\frac{(n + i-1)}{i} s_{k}(x_1)z^n $$

The other identity is given by

$$ \prod_{i=1}^{m}\prod_{j= 1}^{n}(1+(x_i + y_i))= \sum_{{\mu}\subset \lambda \subset (n^m)}d_{\lambda , \nu} s_{\lambda^{'}}({\bf{x}})s_{\mu}({\bf{y}})\tag{*}$$
$\lambda^{'}$ represent the conjugate partition to lambda.

In $(**)$ if we replace $x_i$ by $x_i +y_1$ we can get an expression on the RHS involving
$s_{\lambda}(x_1+ y_1, x_2+y_1,\ldots)$. Now we can do it all $y_j$ and get such expression. I guess then the question reduces to find
$$s_{\lambda}(x_1 + y_1 , x_2 +y_1, \ldots) $$
can be expressed in terms of Schur functions ?

Comment: In your equation $*$ should $y_i$ be replaced with $y_j$? Also what is $w$? A non-negative integer?

Comment: Yes w is non negative. We replace x_i by x_i + y_1 in similar way we can replace it by x_i + y_j