# Addition theorem for Schur function in multivariable

Tags: co.combinatorics, mp.mathematical-physics, enumerative-combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics, young-tableaux

Working with the following problem [Expansion in Schur function of negative binomial exponent](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418405/expansion-in-schur-function-of-negative-binomial-exponent?noredirect=1#comment1074115_418405)

I need to find the expansion of
$$ s_{\lambda}(x_1 + y , x_2 +y, \ldots, x_n +y)$$
in terms of schur function.
In Macdonald's book, page 47 problem 10 gives an expression for
$$s_{\lambda}(x_1 + 1 , x_2 +1, \ldots, x_n +1) = \sum_{\mu\subset \lambda}d_{\lambda \mu}s_{\mu}(x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n) $$
where $d_{\lambda \mu} = det\left(\binom{\lambda_i+n-i}{\mu_i +i-j} \right)_{1\leq i,j\leq 1}$.
So can we get an expression in we replace 1 by $y$?
Also I wonder about the remark 3 made in page 74 facts that true in $\lambda$ ring
if $S^{\lambda \setminus \mu} = \sum_{\nu}c^{\lambda}_{\mu \nu}S^{\nu}$ then
$$ S^{\lambda}(x+y) = \sum_{\lambda} S^{\lambda \setminus \mu}(x) S^{\mu}(y)\tag{**} $$

So I am wondering if it's true in the case of the Schur function in multivariable. We have an expression for the skew Schur function in terms of the Little Richardson coefficient that is $s_{\lambda \setminus \mu} = \sum_{\nu}c^{\lambda}_{\mu \nu}s_{\nu}$. What is the relation between $s_{\lambda \setminus \mu} $ and $d_{\lambda \mu}$ ?

Comment: The formula for $s_\lambda(x_1+y,\dots,x_n+y)$ is obtained by "homogenizing" the one for $s_\lambda(x_1+1,\dots,x_n+1)$, i.e., $$ s_\lambda(x_1+y,\dots,x_n+y)=\sum_{\mu\subset \lambda}d_{\lambda\mu} y^{|\lambda/\mu|}s_\mu(x_1,\dots,x_n).$$ For a simplification of this formula, see Problem 87 at https://klein.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ch7supp.pdf. For your question about $S^\lambda(x+y)$, perhaps you don't understand the notation. Here $x$ is a set $x_1,x_2,\dots$ of variables, and similarly for $y$, and $S^\lambda(x+y)$ means $s_\lambda(x_1,x_2,\dots, y_1,y_2,\dots)$.

Comment: I see thanks for the comment, so the problem 87 the map means you are shifting the variable $x_i$ by $x_i +1$ so if I have finitely many variables say $x_1 , \ldots x_n$ then $t$ is $n$. Hence the corresponding schur function formula

Comment: So if this true then I think I can write a schur function expansion of $ \prod_{i=1}^{m}\prod_{j= 1}^{n}(1-z(x_i + y_i))^{-w} \tag{*}$

Comment: Can you please give me some easy reference for hook content formula for skew Schur function also for $f^{\lambda \ \mu}$

Comment: I am looking for the definition of a content of a skew young diagram. In problem 87 you mentioned $u\in \lambda \setminus \mu$ $c(u)$.